# ionic5 webview app browser events are not sync with android device back button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using a website in the ionic-5 web-view app. When I go back to the previous page in the Ionic app, Android device back button is not responding. I am unable to go back to previous page in the Ionic app. Ionic web-view app events are not in sync with Android device back button. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle hardware back button using platform

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
  // route to previous page or component
});
```